# How to Assign a Variable Name in a #define (Boost related Mem Leak)?

Tags: memory, boost, memory-leaks, macros

I've ran Memory Validator on an application we're developing, and I've found that a Macro expressions we've defined is at the root of about 90% of the leaks. #define O_set.

Now, our macros are defined as follows:

```
#define O_SET_VALUE(ValueType, Value) boost::shared_ptr<ValueType>(new ValueType(Value))
.
.
#define O_set O_SET_VALUE
```

However, according to the Boost web site (at: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm):

> A simple guideline that nearly
>   eliminates the possibility of memory
>   leaks is: always use a named smart
>   pointer variable to hold the result of
>   new. Every occurence of the new
>   keyword in the code should have the
>   form: shared_ptr p(new Y); It is,
>   of course, acceptable to use another
>   smart pointer in place of shared_ptr
>   above; having T and Y be the same
>   type, or passing arguments to Y's
>   constructor is also OK.
>
> If you observe this guideline, it
>   naturally follows that you will have
>   no explicit deletes; try/catch
>   constructs will be rare.

This leads me to believe that this is indeed the major cause of our memory leaks. Or am I being naive or completely out of my depth here?

Question is, is there a way to work around the mentioned issue, with the above macro #defines?

Update:
I'm using them, for example, like this:

`return O_set(int, 1);`
`_time_stamp(O_set(TO_DateTime, TO_DateTime()))` (_time_stamp is a member of a certain class)

I'm working in Windows and used MemoryValidator for tracking the Memory Leaks - according to it there are leaks - as I state, the root of most of which (according to the stack traces) come down to that macro #define.

Comment: First of all, how are you using this macro?  Are you then assigning the created smart pointer to another smart pointer?

Comment: Try replacing your macro with `#define O_SET_VALUE(ValueType, Value) boost::make_shared<ValueType>(Value)` (which is more efficient than what you have anyway) so that your macro does not use `new` directly, but rather relegates that to Boost itself. If it still leaks, then I think your assessment that this macro is the cause of your leaks is incorrect.

Comment: ildjarn, if I could vote your answer up I'd do it in a heartbeat.

This suggestion both improved performance and cut the mem leak reports by a bit more than half (at least for limited or cursory testing). Thanks.

Comment: ildjarn,
It seems that the change might have caused a different leak - one that that now tracks, through the make_shared function, to sp_counted_impl_pd code. This block in shared_count.hpp:
`try
{
pi_ = new sp_counted_impl_pd<P, D>(p, d);
}
catch()
{
d(p); // delete p
throw;
}`
And this one:
`try
{
  pi_ = new sp_counted_impl_p<Y>( p );
}
catch()
{boost::checked_delete( p );
throw;}`

Anyone might have any idea why that's happening?

Answer (score 0):

Smart pointers are tricky. The first thing I would do is to check your code for any 'new' statement which isn't inside either macro.

Then you have to think about how the pointers are being used; if you pass a smart pointer by reference, the reference counter isn't increased, for example.

Another thing to check is all instances of '.get()', which is a big problem if you are working with a legacy code base or other developers who don't understand the point of using smart pointers!  (this is more to do with preventing random crashes than memory links persé, but worth checking)

Also, you might want to consider why you are using a macro for all smart pointer creation. Boost supply different smart pointers for different purposes. There isn't a one size fits all solution.   Good old std::auto_ptr is fine for most uses, except storing in standard containers, but you knew that already.

The most obvious and overlooked aspect is,  do you *really* need to 'new' something. C++ isn't Java,  if you can avoid creating dynamic objects you are better off doing so.

If you are lucky enough to be working with a *NIX platform (you don't mention, sorry) then try the leak checking tool with Valgrind. It's very useful. There are similar tools available for windows, but often using you're software skilz is best.

Good luck.